# How to filter a nested filed averaged on Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, filtering, django-queryset

My serializer is made with an aggregation of a nested field, and I compute an average of a number on these nested objects.

The `Question` object is nested with a `Difficulty_Question` Object (a 'ForeignKey' relation on the `Difficulty_Question` Object).
`Difficulty_Question` have a 'difficulty' field that I averaged and aggregated on the `Question` object. (see `get_difficulty` function)

I would like to filter the `Question` object with a range of difficulty.

My serializer looks like:

**serializer.py:**

```
class QuestionListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    difficulty = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_difficulty(self, obj):
        average = obj.difficulty_questions.all().aggregate(Avg('difficulty')).get('difficulty__avg')
        if average is None:
            return 0
        return average

    class Meta:
        model = models.Question
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'difficulty',
        )
```

I try to filter this django object by difficulty, but all I can do is filtering all the objects of the nested field, not the average of all the objects..

**view.py**

```
class QuestionFilter(FilterSet):
    difficulty_questions__difficulty__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='difficulty_questions__difficulty', lookup_expr='gt')
    difficulty_questions__difficulty__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='difficulty_questions__difficulty', lookup_expr='lt')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Question
        fields = {'difficulty_questions__difficulty': ['lt', 'gt']}

class QuestionViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Question.objects.all()

    serializer_class = serializers.QuestionSerializer

    action_serializers = {
        'retrieve': serializers.QuestionSerializer,
        'list': serializers.QuestionListSerializer,
        'create': serializers.QuestionSerializer
    }

    filter_class = QuestionFilter

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        if hasattr(self, 'action_serializers'):
            if self.action in self.action_serializers:
                return self.action_serializers[self.action]

        return super(QuestionViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

I also use different serializers for the detail and list views...

Any ideas of how I could filter my "Question" object by average of the 'difficulty' field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
class QuestionListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    difficulty_avg = serializers.IntegerField()
```

view

```
class QuestionFilter(FilterSet):
    difficulty_avg__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='difficulty_avg', lookup_expr='gt')
    difficulty_avg__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='difficulty_avg', lookup_expr='lt')

    class Meta:
         model = models.Question
         fields = {'difficulty_avg': ['lt', 'gt']}


class QuestionViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Question.objects.annotate(difficulty_avg=Avg('difficulty_questions__difficulty'))
```